onScroll is not working for android mobile
I am new to react-native so this might be a newbie doubt. I am working with react-native FlatList component, here I am trying to implement loading more data on scroll up and scroll down gesture. The code is working fine in web browser view but for android mobile the onScroll is glitching, it is not working everytime.
const handleScroll = (event) => {
        const scrollPosition = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        if (scrollPosition <= 0 && !loading && !scrollingUp) {
            setScrollingUp(true);
            const scrollOffsetBefore = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
            loadMoreDates('top').then(() => {
                const scrollOffsetAfter = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
                const addedContentHeight = scrollOffsetAfter - scrollOffsetBefore;
                flatListRef?.current.scrollToOffset({ offset: addedContentHeight, animated: false });
                setScrollingUp(false);
            });
        }
    };

-----
<FlatList
                ref={flatListRef}
                data={dateList}
                renderItem={renderDateItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.date}`}
                onEndReached={() => loadMoreDates('down')}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
                onScroll={handleScroll}
                ListFooterComponent={loading ? <Text>Loading...</Text> : null}
                ListHeaderComponent={loading ? <Text>Loading...</Text> : null}
                style={[{ marginTop: 20 }]}
            />

I know about onRefresh prop but using it will not give a seemless scroll for user. Also I have tried looking around the internet but I am only getting articles about scroll to top prop. Would be great if anyone can tell where should I research around.

have you checked using scrollEventThrottle prop in FlatList, which can ensure that the onScroll function is called at regular intervals scrollEventThrottle={16}

try change <FlatList ... to <Animated.FlatList...
